# Change only update and delete rule of a set of tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, alter-table

Normally I change the update and the delete rule of a table by dropping the foreign key and recreating it again. example below:

`ALTER TABLE xyz DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_1`;

`ALTER TABLE xyz ADD CONSTRAINT  fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES batch_details a) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;`

But if I have  a set of tables then doing like this becomes tedious.
Although I can see the update and delete rule for all tables using

`select * from information_schema.referential_constraints;`

I have also tried:

`update information_schema.referential_constraints set update_rule='CASCADE',delete_rule='CASCADE' where table_name='x';`

But it wants root privileges which I cannot give.
Please help how to do it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have permission on the server to do that? Maybe you have no rights to update this table or no rights to update table structures at all

Comment: Yes I can update using the basic alter commands given above

Comment: I mean to update `information_schema.referential_constraints`

Comment: No I am not willing to do it via root user or user with admin like permissions

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to create a set of administrative stored procedures that you can reuse to perform these operations, then call such procedures -- either in a loop in an outer procedure, or from a script.

For example, you could loop through the results of your original `information_schema` `SELECT` query (perhaps using a cursor in a procedure), and then call your new administrative procedures for each row returned.

Here is an administrative stored procedure you can use to drop a foreign key. You can use the same principles to create a similar procedure for adding constraints.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `admin_drop_fk`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `admin_drop_fk`(
    fk_name VARCHAR(64),    
    table_name VARCHAR(64),
    db_name  VARCHAR(64)
)
BEGIN
SET @sqlexec := 
CONCAT
(
    'SELECT @i := COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = \'',
    fk_name, 
    '\' AND TABLE_NAME = \'', 
    table_name,
    '\' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = \'',
    db_name,
    '\''
);

SELECT CONCAT('Executing: "', @sqlexec, '"') AS 'Info';
PREPARE lookup FROM @sqlexec;
EXECUTE lookup;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE lookup;

IF @i > 0 THEN
    SET @sqlexec := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', db_name, '`.`', table_name, '` DROP FOREIGN KEY `', fk_name, '`');
    SELECT CONCAT('Executing: "', @sqlexec, '"') AS 'Info';
    PREPARE statement FROM @sqlexec;
    EXECUTE statement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
    SELECT CONCAT('Successful execution of: "', @sqlexec, '"') AS 'Info';
ELSE
    SELECT CONCAT('Warning: Foreign key `', fk_name, '` does not exist on `', db_name, '`.`', table_name, '`') AS 'Warning';
END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```